# Subscribe to observable get event *and* full history

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm playing around with [System.Reactive](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) and looking to achieve the following:

- A timer fires an event every 3 seconds
- A filesystemwatcher fires events in case a file is changed (another app appending to the file) - and only when a new name is added - fire an event. That works very nicely with `DistinctUntilChanged()`. (in sample code mocked by keyboard input)

Do something *whichever comes first*. That works with `.Merge` - all good.
But in the subscriber to this merged Observable - I would like to access all the values that were 'emitted' by the filesystemwatcher (so csvAppendMock).
I've seen multiple methods in IObservable like `ToList()` or `ForEachAsync` or `ToListObservable` - but none of them give the desired result in the console app.

**Q:** How can I subscribe to the `csvAppendMock`, get `DistinctUntilChanged` *AND* get access to all the values that were produced (without keeping a local list and appending it myself of course).

```
private static async Task Main()
{
    var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Select(_ => DateTime.Now.ToString());
    var csvAppendMock = Input().ToObservable().DistinctUntilChanged();

    // Creating an observable of a timer merged with a change in a CSV file (simulated by Console.Readline
    // Event firest whichever comes first - that works fine
    var s = timer.Merge(csvAppendMock).Subscribe(s =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($">> {s}");

        // How do I get all the values from csvAppendMock?
        // csvAppendMock.ToList results in thread locks?
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Input()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Providing some more info. The code above produces the following output:
[image]

Which almost what I'm looking for:

- The lines with the timestamp are when the Observable Interval triggers - they show up every 3 seconds
- `test`, `test` and `test2` is the stuff I type
- `>>test` is the merged observable that triggers on the text I type - and as you can see, I typed `test` twice, but only once you see `>>test` because of `DistinctUntilChanged`

What I need is to access to the historic values that triggered `csvAppendMock` - so ( ["test", "test2"] ).

Here's code that does not work:

```
        var s = timer.Merge(csvAppendMock).Subscribe(s =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($">> {s}");

            // Goal: print out here *all* values observed by csvAppendMock - so a working version 
            // of what I thought the following would do:
            Console.WriteLine("All observed values thusfar are ...");
            var itemsSoFar = csvAppendMock.ToList();
            foreach ( var item in itemsSoFar)
            {
                // Code does not work - will get 'stuck' here - in the sense
                // will print 'All observed values...' then nothing
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        });
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please [edit] your question to include some kind of marble diagram to show, which value should be generated at some point, how the observables should be connected and what the result should be (and when). It might sound like you want `ReplaySubject` or `Replay()` or `CombineLatest()`, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Your "input" stream generates the values `[test, test, test2]`, but you don't want the same value so you use `DistinctUntilChanged()` to get `[test, test2]`, but then you said you actually *want* all the generated values. That is in conflict with using `DistinctUntilChanged()`. Maybe you want the whole content of the CSV file as a value, so you get `["test", "test\ntest2"]`. It is still not exactly clear which values are generated at what point and how the result should look like for the subscription.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this - you simply can add `.Replay()` or one of its overloads after `.DistinctUntilChanged()` - this is likewise @Progman suggested.

```
var csvAppendMock = Input()
    .ToObservable()
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Replay();
```

Please do not consider this as an answer - it is added only for better visibility of possible obvious solution.